# Get OAuth access token to Drive API for AppEngine from an Android application

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-play-services

What I want to achieved:

Get the access token to access the Google Drive API from an AppEngine application, from the user Android smartphone.

I have an Android application and a GAE server with endpoints.
Is there another way than creating a webview directing to a GAE handler (https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/python#authorization)?

I would like to use play service since it should be more convenient, but then i am stuck with the android client_secret and so on.

Thanks

### EDIT

I tried what was suggested below, but I got this exception

```
06-14 18:07:33.032: W/System.err(12378): com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
06-14 18:07:33.052: W/System.err(12378):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
06-14 18:07:33.052: W/System.err(12378):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
06-14 18:07:33.052: W/System.err(12378):    at edu.kaist.wst660.bmaingret.android.MainActivity.getAndUseAuthTokenBlocking(MainActivity.java:361)
06-14 18:07:33.057: W/System.err(12378):    at edu.kaist.wst660.bmaingret.android.MainActivity$10.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:405)
06-14 18:07:33.057: W/System.err(12378):    at edu.kaist.wst660.bmaingret.android.MainActivity$10.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
06-14 18:07:33.062: W/System.err(12378):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
06-14 18:07:33.062: W/System.err(12378):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-14 18:07:33.062: W/System.err(12378):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-14 18:07:33.062: W/System.err(12378):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
06-14 18:07:33.067: W/System.err(12378):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
06-14 18:07:33.072: W/System.err(12378):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
06-14 18:07:33.072: W/System.err(12378):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I have seen more verbose exceptions...

Note: I follow this link http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html
with this scope oauth2:server:client_id:xxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com:api_scope:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

Answer (score 0):

Suggest reading the following document that I believe addresses the situation you describe: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth

Comment: Hum , seems like what i want indeed. I'll try it and get back :) Thanks ("Cross-client"... makes sense)

Comment: Regarding my upadet. I just tried with a regular scope (oauth2:https://blabla/drive.file) and it actually worked... So it must be a problem with the scope

Comment: So I tried with Postman for chrome. I had some problem but manage to make it work, so i will probably use webview... Since the solution doesn't seem to work